# PhpChart or Jqplot line thresholding

Tags: charts, line, jqplot

I am new in jqplot or phpChart. I am using jqplot for representing a line chart with a specific color. But what I need is to set some point of the line in different color. like if my line is `(x1,y1), (x2, y2), (x3,y3), (x4, y4)....(xn, yn)`. I want from (`x2, y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)` in different color.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did hard work last summer on jqplot because of a project. But there is no such functionality by the library itself. I had the same problems so i decided to render more lines like that:

[image: jqplot Chart]

In my chart i wanted to do the same with Alarm 1,2 and 3. But this wasn't possible so i did just make 3 lines instead of render a part of the line in a different color. For doing that what you want you have to change a lot of the basic functionality and then you will not be able to update it sometimes...